# Normal Family complex

Tags: complex-analysis

I search about a family of holomorphic complex function that not normal but their derivative is normal. 
the definition of normality similar to Montel's Thrm

Answer (score 0):

An example is the sequence $z, 2z, 3z, \ldots$ in domain $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You mean $f_n(z) = nz,$  $n=1,2,3,...$. not normal in $C$ and                                                                                  $f'_n(z) = n , $ is normal in $C$.